# In how many ways can $7$ items be selected from $14$ items of $3$ types so that there is at least one of each type?

Tags: combinatorics

There are 14 items of 3 types: 2 of the first type, 4 of the second type and 8 of the third type. You must select 7 items so that there is at least one item of each type.

My solution

$3! \cdot {11 \choose 4} = 330 \cdot 6 = 1980$

Comment: Why $3!$? Explain the logic there.

Comment: This is far too high.  There are fewer than $10$  ways to do it.  Among other things, you appear to be ignoring the number of available items of each type.

Comment: @lulu Really? My answer is higher than the OP's. Am I making a mistake here?

Comment: @Deepak  Yes.  You are badly overcounting.  If, say, your selection has $5$ of type three, then you count it at least $5$ times.

Comment: @lulu Let me think through this, but I'll delete my answer first to be safe.

Comment: @Deepak  As a quick way to do it, note that you must choose either $1$ or $2$ of type one, and one of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ of type two.  All choices lead to valid triples and type three items present no difficulty. There are $2\times 4=8$ ways to do that, and that choice determines the triple.

Comment: @lulu Ah OK, because you're guaranteed to get an item of the third type. Thanks.

Comment: @Deepak  Right. And because there are enough type three items so that you can ignore the cap.  Should say:  I am assuming that all objects of a given type are indistinguishable.  If that is not the case, then for each of my $8$ cases you'll need to consider the number of ways to select within a single type.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. Should've written some working down.

Comment: Are the items of the same type distinguishable?

Comment: @user Items of the same type indistinguishable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to finding the number of integral solutions to the equation
$$ a + b + c = 7 ~\text{ s.t. }\\
1 \le a \le 2 \\
1 \le b \le 4 \\
1 \le c \le 8$$

Change the variables $a' = a - 1, b' = b - 1, c' = c - 1$
$$ a' + b' + c' = 4 ~\text{ s.t. }\\
0 \le a' \le 1 \\
0 \le b' \le 3 \\
0 \le c' \le 7$$

Note that since $a', b', c'$ are non-negative, the last contraint is the same as $0 \le c' \le 4$

The number of solutions to this can be found out by simple inclusion-exclusion
$$ \binom{6}{2} - \binom{4}{2} - \binom{2}{2} = 15 - 6 - 1 = 8 $$

$\displaystyle\binom{6}{2}$ is the number of non-negative integral solutions to $a' + b' + c' = 4$

$\displaystyle\binom{4}{2}$ is the number of non-negative integral solutions to $a' + b' + c' = 4$ with $a' > 1$

$\displaystyle\binom{2}{2}$ is the number of non-negative integral solutions to $a' + b' + c' = 4$ with $b' > 3$

Note that any other exclusion case has zero possibilities because if $c' > 4$, the sum of $a', b', c'$ cannot be $4$

The same is true when both $a' > 1$ and $b' > 3$

Comment: What kind of formula did you use to obtain $\binom42$ and $\binom22$?

Comment: @user The number of non-negative integral solutions to $a′+b′+c′=4$ with $a'>1$ (or $a'\ge2$) is the same as the number of non-negative integral solutions to $a''+b′+c′=2$ where $a'' = a '- 2$, which we know is $\binom{2+3-1}{3-1} = \binom{4}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution under the assumption that items of the same type are instead distinguishable.

Without the restriction of at least one of each type, there are $$\binom{2+4+8}{7}=\binom{14}{7}=3432$$ choices.
Applying the principle of inclusion-exclusion yields
\begin{align}
&\binom{2+4+8}{7}
-\left[\binom{2}{0}\binom{4+8}{7}+\binom{4}{0}\binom{2+8}{7}\right]
+ \binom{2}{0}\binom{4}{0}\binom{8}{7} \\
&= 3432
-\left[792+120\right]
+8 \\
&= 2528.
\end{align}